# Rally custom list query not working on string custom field

Tags: rally

I have a custom field being added on user story (HierarchicalRequirement) level.
The WSAPI documentation shows the following details for the field:
**c_CustomFieldName**
Required    false
Type    string
Max Length  32,768
Sortable    true
Explicit Fetch  false
Query Expression Operators  contains, !contains, =, !=

When trying to create a report using Custom List to identify user stories where this field is empty, I add (c_CustomFieldName = "") to the query.
And yet, the result shows rows where this field is not empty. 
How can that be?
I tried querying on null, but it didn't work.

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work- are you getting errors, or just incorrect data?  It almost seems like it's ignoring your query altogether.

I tried to repro both with the custom list app and against wsapi directly and the following all worked as expected:

```
(c_CustomText = "") //empty
(c_CustomText = null) //empty

(c_CustomText != "") //non-empty
(c_CustomText != null) //non-empty
```

It's possible you're running into some weird data-specific edge case in your data.  It may be worth following up with support.

Comment: the field is called "c_ProductOwnerTempField" and is on user story level.
I want to get a list of all USs where this field is empty.

I tried creating a custom list with any of these queries:
(c_ProductOwnerTempField = "")
(c_ProductOwnerTempField = null)
(ProductOwnerTempField = "")
(ProductOwnerTempField = null)

All of them return the same number of results. 
All of them have some rows where the field is empty and others a non-empty.
This means that none of the above filterings is working